LED light bulb is flickering when switched on
I am a Physics Major student and have to do a project in our end sem.
Since we read a lot of theory and workings and very less practicals, I am a bit weak in electronics.
So here is the problem.
Our project is to study the response characteristics of LDR with distance and wattage of bulbs, and for showing a demo of its application, we are to make an Automatic Light Bulb.
When connected it works perfectly, but the light bulb is flickering, and it is observable.
Circuit diagram :

Result :

Open Circuit: Open Circuit of Photosensitive Bulb

Smart Bulb Holder: Smart holder based on the above idea



Please draw a proper schematic. This site has a schematic drawing tool for this very purpose.

@qrk When I click on the Schematic drawing tool it says something like , Schematic is not supported for some touch devices. And due to this I have to share a unacceptable circuit diagram.

What did you expect? On the bench, you have the LDR pointed more-or-less directly at the bulb you're controlling! Of course it's going to try to turn itself off. You need to arrange the LDR so it can't see the light that it's controlling. In the second video, there still may be enough reflected light hitting the LDR.

@DaveTweed Then what about the Smart holder video, bruh ! In that video , the bulb itself is not interfering with LDR.

Likely, this is due to feedback, lamp -> light ->photoresistor ->lamp. However, many LED's flicker under pulsed voltage, anyway. Use an ancient but honorable incandescent lamp.

The smart holder probably has some kind of filtering to prevent that from happening bruh.

@vir I guess I could introduce a Capacitor to the circuit.

@DrMoishePippik Got it , Brother.

So the light turns off when the LDR is illuminated. Your first problem is you have to decuple the light generated by the lamp from the LDR - you set up what's known as a hysteric oscillator - light comes on, hits LDR, power gets cut from lamp, lamp goes out, LDR is dark, power is applied to lamp, light comes on, ad infinium. The second order issue may be that your using an LED-based luminary which has its own electronics controller which behaves way different than the incandescent lamp, especially under your operating conditions, that you've deceptively shown in your wiring diagram.
By the way, you can do the same thing by putting a mirror in front of one of these devil dogs. Bonus: the internal circuitry is almost identical to your technology:

